# Woocommerce checking stock of several products in a DRY way?

Tags: php, wordpress, stock

How can i check the stock of several products of several products of the same parent category 
in a DRY way? I would either need to get the total stock and / or check that the stock of any given product doesn't fall under a certain threshold.

So far, i know how to retrieve the stock for each individual product, i would need (1) to return the value of the total amount of stocks and (2) to check if no individual value falls under a certain threshold.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 'name_of_my_category',
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$name_of_my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($name_of_my_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($name_of_my_query->have_posts()) : 
        $name_of_my_query->the_post();
        $product = get_product( $name_of_my_query->post->ID );


echo $product->stock;
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

At this stage, i can only think of repeating this code for each product, assigning each value returned to a different variable and sum them up... quite a lengthy process, i'm sure there must be a simpler way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of argument arrays, and loop through them with a foreach statement:

```
$threshold = 100;

$args_array = array(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'product_cat' => 'name_of_my_category',
        'orderby' =>'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ),
    array(
        'post_type' => 'product2',
        'product_cat' => 'name_of_my_category2',
        'orderby' =>'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ),
    array(
        'post_type' => 'product3',
        'product_cat' => 'name_of_my_category3',
        'orderby' =>'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    )
);


foreach ($args_array as $args) {
    $name_of_my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($name_of_my_query->have_posts()) : 
        while ($name_of_my_query->have_posts()) : 
            $name_of_my_query->the_post();
            $product = get_product( $name_of_my_query->post->ID );
            echo $product->stock;
            if((int)$product->stock <= $threshold){
                //do stuff here to alert yourself that stock is low
                echo "Stock is low on".$product->name;
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lars! Brillant, just that bit of knowledge that tells the difference between a newbie and an expert! Grateful you could bridge that gap! Just a clarification, to make sure : that echo statement will trigger each and everytime that it the loop finds an understocked item, correct? What if i need that echo to trigger if at least one item is understocked? Thanks again!

Comment: Any hint as to how i could get the totals of the array stock as well? Thanks!